# How can I install a custom time zone on a Windows machine

Tags: .net, windows, timezone

I know that I can create custom time zones in .Net using the TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone() method and use them within applications. Is it possible to install or register a time zone created in this way on a machine so that it will be available through a call to TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()?

We want to use a time zone that moves in and out of daylight savings daily over a few weeks for the purpose of testing a system that is being made more time zone aware.

From this article I see it is possible to update the registry in order to do this but the article advises against this and the format also differs somewhat from the time zone info serialized with TimeZoneInfo.ToSerializedString(). Is there perhaps a tool that might automate updating the registry with the data from the custome time zone to achieve what we want?

Comment: Do you actually need all of Windows to know about it? An alternative would be to use my [Noda Time project](http://nodatime.org) at which point you can implement your own time zone relatively easily, and use it fairly easily from all the applications that use Noda Time...

Comment: I'm not really sure at this point. I've been asked to investigate the possibility of doing this to help our business intelligence team with testing reports. I'm not sure whether they will be able to use a custom time zone created in code from either NodaTime or TimeZoneInfo. It's possible that they need access to the custom time zone from third-party apps. I'm waiting for them to get out of a meeting before I can ask them, just probing options at the moment.